# Select2 multiple creates duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

My Select2 box is working oddly with multiple selection turned on.
When I submit my form it sends duplicate post data in a mirror-like fashion.

For example, I select

`'United States','United Kingdom','Ireland'`

It posts (Reported by firebug and shown in html result)

`'United States','United Kingdom','Ireland','United Kingdom','United States'`

My HTML for countries(slimmed down)...

```
<select multiple  name="country" id="country" class="select2" data-placeholder="Select Country/Countries" style="width:220px;"  required>
  <option value=""></option> <option value="United States">United States</option> <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> <option value="Albania">Albania</option><option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

And my JS only calls

```
  $('.select2').select2();
```

I have no idea why this might be happening. I'm using other JS libraries like Bootstrap,jQueryValidate,and Zebra DatePicker, but I don't think they would interfere.

Comment: Can you print out $("#country").val() before validation and after validation? Allso would be intresting to see its value after you select new value. As normally select2 will not put duplicates there.

Answer (score 1):

You may have called $('.select2').select2(); function twice. I faced the same issue and the reason was that I had called the function twice for same dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#country").select2();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question